# get list of all ALL widgets available in GWT

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to get whole list of widgets available by GWT .
like `Button`, `ListBox`, `CheckBox` etc ...

I want to show the whole list in my running GWT application.

I was thinking If i can get all the classes which extends Widget/ UiObject

May be something like this can help(using Reflections library)

```
Reflections reflectionsWidget = new Reflections("com.google.gwt.widget");

Set<Class<? extends Widget>> allWidgets = reflectionsWidget.getSubTypesOf(Widget.class);
```

But this works on server side ,If i try this it gives me empty list.

Please guide

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the list will never change during runtime, it may be a good idea to create it as a static resource during compile time. The resulting class should be in the client package and then you can use it in client code.